# Not able to access the driver Globally

Tags: java, selenium

The below code I was running and I have declared my **webdriver** globally but it is continuously displaying the null pointer error i.e the driver is not accessible to the other method in the same class.

```
Please looking forward to the solution!
package selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNG {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Test

    public void starting_point()

    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\swagatika.mohapatra\\OneDrive - Qualitest Group\\Desktop\\selenium\\DRIVER\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://www.google.com");

        

    }

    @Test(groups = { "demo" })

    public void clicck_Element() throws Exception {

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='gLFyf gsfi']")).sendKeys("Hellow");

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

Comment: at what line do you get nullPointerException ? pls share exception stack track also.

Comment: PASSED: starting_point
FAILED: clicck_Element
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at selenium.TestNG.clicck_Element(TestNG.java:45)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have just given declaration globally `WebDriver driver;` right ?

Now you have 2 @Test Methods, and there is no priority or dependency. So TestNG will run these two test methods in lexicographical order.

In that way `click_Element()` method will get chance first and since webdriver object you have created in `starting_Point()` method you will see nullPointerException.